# Проблемы с std::min

Tags: c++

Извините за эмоции, какого черта вот этот код не хочет компилироваться ?

```
#include <curl.h> 
#include <iostream> 


int main()
{
    size_t my_min_in = std::min(1, 2);   //Ошибка!! Требуется идентификатор
}
```

Если curl.h убрать, то ошибка пропадает!

Какое то пересечение названий что ли происходит ??
Но ведь тут используется пространство имен std же.
:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку в `curl.h` (или включаемом из него другом файле) определен *макрос* `min`, вы получаете после его раскрытия

```
size_t my_min_in = std::(((1) < (2)) ? (1) : (2));
```

Что, понятно, не компилируется...

Подозреваю, что это определение подсасывается из системных заголовочных файлов windows, так что добавление первой строкой

```
#define  NOMINMAX
```

решает эту проблему.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот жеш как бывает.